# PHPBB Custom BBCodes Using PHP Scripts?

Tags: php, curl, bbcode, phpbb

With PHPBB is it possible to use PHP scripts with custom BBCodes?

An example use would be if i wanted to grab today's weather with Curl and then display it on a forum post as text data.

I have tried to add php code directly in the BBCode but it does not work, i have also tried to return an echo from JS but it didn't seem to work either.

I also tried this but it did not work:

```
<!-- PHP --><?php echo 'hello'; ?><!-- ENDPHP -->
```

How would i run some PHP code in a custom BBCode?

Comment: I wish people would say what they expected to happen and what really happened instead of saying "it didn't work".

Comment: It is fairly simple, basically if the bbcode usage was [abc][/abc] and the html replacement was the code i tried above then adding [abc][/abc] to a post should make the text hello appear in the post.

Comment: So basically in your BBCode parser you want anything between `<?php ?>` to be replaced with `eval($content)` ? That's a  very very **very** bad idea.

Comment: Well i just need to grab the result from a PHP script i place in root or a new dir like customphp/ then grab the results in a bbcode.

Comment: This is just getting more and more unclear as to what you're trying to do. If it's just PHP code somewhere on your server how does BBCode get involved? WIll the PHP script itself generate the BBCode?

Comment: Because i want the results to show in a post whenever someone uses the BBCode. The PHP script would generate and echo text to be wrapped in HTML or actual HTML code itself. So say for example the BBCode was [rndsite][/rndsite] and the HTML replacement was <iframe src="https://example.com?={RandomPageID}"></iframe> then the PHP script would be generating the {RandomPageID} value and i need to be able to grab the {RandomPageID} value in the BBCode. Using something like "https://example.com?=<?php echo '132'; ?>" just doesn't seem to work as it blocks PHP in the HTML replacement for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure I fully understand the question but:

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php you can add a content handling callback, e.g.:

```
$BBHandler = bbcode_create([        
    'abc'=> [ 'type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 
               'open_tag'=>'<p>',
               'close_tag'=>'</p>',
               'content_handling' => function () { return "hello"; }
            ]
]);

echo bbcode_parse($BBHandler,"[abc][/abc] word"); //"Should" echo hello world
```

I am basing this on the [PHP BBCode module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)